# I've created my first application for backtesting trades, so could you give me some feedback and suggestions for modifications?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, dashboard, pyalgotrade

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ammtjm/Trade_Simulation_DashBoard)

Thanks for opening this.

I am a beginner in algorithmic trading and application development, and I have recently created a program. I would greatly appreciate your feedback, suggestions, and contributions to help improve this project.

While the basic functionality of the application is in place, I recognize that there are areas where the project can be improved. As a beginner, I am seeking feedback, suggestions, and critiques from the experienced developers in this community to help enhance the project.

The current features of the Trade Simulation Dashboard include:

- Interactive visualizations and metrics
- Minimal and single-page dashboard
- Comparison of the trading strategy's performance with a buy-and-hold strategy

The technologies used in this project are:

- Python
- Dash
- Plotly
- Pandas

I am expecting to receive feedback and suggestions from the community regarding:

- Code optimization and best practices
- Improving the user interface and user experience
- Adding new features such as transaction fees and comparison with other saved strategies
- Identifying and fixing any potential bugs or performance issues

I am open to any ideas and critiques that can help enhance the Trade Simulation Dashboard and make it a more valuable tool for traders.

Thank you for reading the text so far.

Comment: @user19077881 Any question on Code Review must contain the code to be reviewed, there is no code in this question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I understood that, but I didn't put it up because I wanted a review of the whole (e.g., over/under on features, improvements to the functional split of the application files, etc.), not a question on specific code in the application.

Comment: 1) you asked for a code review on the wrong site. 2) On the Code Review Site we can only review code posted in the body of the question. We can use GitHub repositories for references, but the code you want reviewed must be in the body of the question. On Code Review you can post up to 64K of code.

Comment: ok, I understand it. Sorry